# NetTopologySuite squash multipolygon to polygon

Tags: .net-core, geometry, nettopologysuite, geoapi

I am working in aspnetcore using the most up to date GeoAPI and NetTopologySuite version for core. What I'm trying to do should be fairly simple but I can't seem to find the proper way to do it either through experimentation of googling. Or even what to call it, to be honest, which makes googling harder.

Hopefully someone can kick me in the right direction.

I have a multipolygon which may be made up of one or more polygons. I want to create a buffer around that multipolygon's points out to X distance. This is basically a map overlay with concentric areas of interest. A given point of interest may fall in the original multi polygon's shapes... or it might fall in the first or second buffer area. Kinda like an onion if the core of an onion had random shapes in it.

That first part is simple. Just iterate the multipolygon's points and apply a buffer to each point using the buffer method:

```
var bufferZonePoints = new List<IGeometry>();
foreach(var point in multiPolygon.Coordinates)
{
   bufferZonePoints.Add(point.Buffer(x));
}

var bufferZone = this.geometryFactory.CreateMultiPolygon(bufferZonePoints);
```

That's fine. But it's giving me another multipolygon made up of thousands of points. When I use this as a map overlay, I get a hurricane of circles following the vague outlines of the original shape sort of looking like a spirograph drawing. All I want is basically the outer boundary of all the buffer circles without all the points in the center.

I tried doing a ConvexHull on the multipolygon and it looked correct at first until I realize that it was shaving off the angles on the outside in order to get the smallest polygon all those points fit into (which is what convex hulls do after all). But that causes problems in the stuff I'm overlaying. Some points of interest may be outside the actual buffer, but be inside if the convex hull decides to round off a bumpy area of the zone. (I hope that makes sense).

Basically what I'm trying to do is take that multipolygon made up of all those buffered points and squash it down into a single polygon made up all the outermost boundaries of the buffers. But without all the spirograph garbage in the middle. I don't really want a ConvexHull. I've also tried Union and the GeometryCombiner class, but none of these are doing what I want.

I don't know if this helps makes this mud any clearer but there is a setting in QGIS that when you plunk down two circles and the circles would overlap they combine into one big blob like soap bubbles and the boundaries in between vanish. That's kinda what I'm trying to do via code.

Does that make sense? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

After continuing to experiment with my mapping tool. It would appear that Union DOES actually give me the result I wanted.

I started with two polygons that were far enough apart to make it obvious what was going on, did a union on them and got back just the shell of the combination of them. As I added more of the buffered points to it, the shame became a bit more obvious.

That's pretty well what I wanted.

Thanks anyway though! Hopefully this will help someone else.